# How to prevent a hover firing on responsive navigation

Tags: jquery, navigation

I am building a responsive navigation and have just run into a problem. The essence of the navigation is for it to be responsive, so you click a 'three-line' button and the menu pops down in the page. The menu supports nested <ul>'s so that inside the menu, you can click a box (on the right) to open the nested menu as well. Now, my issue here is that I only want to open the navigation onclick, not hover.

*In essence:*

- Main nav (desktop): hover over <li> to open the child <ul>
- When under a certain width (media queries) hide it to show a black box to click on, which you can click the next box to open the <ul>

All is working fine, but the hover event to open the *desktop* navigation, is obviously triggering the navigation to open when it's in responsive view. How can I prevent this?

Here's the JSFiddle of the nav, please click the black box: http://bit.ly/ZZJcYk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I'd recommend is to use:
http://modernizr.com/

It will help you in many other ways when developing responsive sites/apps.

By including it, you'll be getting (among other things) classes for your HTML node.

If the user is on a touch device it will be the .touch class, if not, .no-touch.

To make use of this you would do the following with your code:

```
$('.no-touch .nav').on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).children('.nav-submenu').toggle();
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(this).children('.nav-submenu').toggle();
        }
    }, '.nav-item');
```

The `$('.no-touch .nav')` would make sure that this code only executes on no-touch devices, such as desktop. There are other solutions, but using modernizr is something I'd highly recommend in the long run.

Comment: I've managed to do this! I've added an !important to the display none, only inside the media query, and used this jQuery! http://jsfiddle.net/88HLX - I don't think it's too much of a hacky method?

Comment: Hey if it works it works :) There are however much cleaner ways to do all this via CSS only (except the click part to toggle classes). But if you're not aiming for perfect 3rd-party readability this is just fine.

Comment: I've managed to do it Vexter! It was so obvious and relied on no hacks. Inside the media queries, all I did on the hover event was tell the navigation not to open, using .parent:hover .child {display:none} - the child being the <ul>. Sorted!